# Futura Font in TeXworks on Windows

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

I went to this [site](https://www.wfonts.com/font/futura) and downloaded Futura for my windows computer. I extracted the files and saved them in the same location as my code. I also opened up the two that I wanted, Futura Book font and Futura Book Italic, and clicked install.

When I run my code in TeXworks using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX I get an error.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura Book}[ItalicFont={Futura Book Italic}]

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
   \markright{\thechapter\ #1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%\definecolor{BLUE}{HTML}{23afdc}
%\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{a81e2d}
%\definecolor{ORANGE}{HTML}{ea6d3c}
%\definecolor{YELLOW}{HTML}{e6a327}
%\definecolor{GREEN}{HTML}{5fa244}
%\definecolor{INDIGO}{HTML}{005988}
%\definecolor{VIOLET}{HTML}{7B2C8E}

\begin{document}

Please help me write this text in Futura!

\end{document}
```

Here is my error:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/Ethan/Documents/Codex 2.0/untitled-2.tex"
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\bk10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetexconfig\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hxetex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\stringenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tipa\tipa.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tipa\t3enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/wrapfig\wrapfig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/float\float.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/subfiles\subfiles.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/import\import.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyphenat\hyphenat.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg")))Running miktex-makemf.exe...


Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.



The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:



  C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
Couldn't open `Futura Bo.cfg'



hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)




Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log


! Package fontspec Error: The font "Futura Book" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 ...ura Book}[ItalicFont={Futura Book Italic}]
                                                  
?
```

Comment: Could you try to make the code more minimal? I doubt that the whole package loading, the color definitions and the header-related stuff are relevant. And instead of just saying "I got an error" it would be helpful if you told also *which* error.

Comment: ok. Edited my code and provided error.

Comment: As campa says you can drop most of those packages as they are not related to font loading. Reducing to the most minimal case is valuable not just to those trying to help. but often you also discover the source of the problem your self.

Comment: I wanted to leave my packages just in case another user sees an interaction that might hinder the process. It seems silly to remove everything when there might be a solution in the preamble.

Comment: @Pyro1368 If you suspect one of your other packages is causing the error, that’s a good reason to try removing them and finding out!

Comment: Please remember to use `@name` if you are answering someone, otherwise they might not come back to see your comment. See the removal as a debugging tool. (here I don't need to as you as the owner is always informed)

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that you don’t say how you installed the font. On Windows, XeTeX often can’t see it unless it’s installed as a system font. If you run `fc-cache -f -s -v` followed by `fc-match "Futura Book"`, can your TeX installation find the font?

Comment: Try loading it by its filename instead of its display name. The family name XeTeX and LuaTeX support is not always what you'd expect. Loading by filename is more reliable.

Comment: Also LuaLaTeX often seems more forgiving about the fonts than XeLaTeX. For example on my Linux box, I cannot get any TeXLive fonts to load with XeLaTeX (has to be added to some system stuff), LuaLaTeX no issues.

Comment: BTW your latex installation is quite a lot out of date (see the fourth line in the log), you might want to do a full miktex update in both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode (as you have files from both)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should update your MikTeX installation, in case there are important bug fixes.

It sounds as if you’ve put the files in a location where `fontspec` can’t find them.  On Windows, this happens when you install fonts the default way, for your user account only.  That puts them in a hidden subdirectory of your user folder that XeTeX doesn’t search.  I should probably write a comprehensive guide that covers every use case somewhere on this site, but for the purposes of this question, here are your options:

- If you want to use your fonts in other applications, uninstall them from the Fonts control panel, then Install for All Users, as an administrator.  This puts the files in `%WINDIR%\Fonts\`.
- If you only want them for one project, or you want to make sure the correct versions of the fonts get archived with the source so that none of the files you need to compile the document ever get lost, copy them to your project directory.
- If you might want to use them for more than one TeX project, but you don’t want them cluttering up your font menu, put them in a local TeX tree.  Since you’re using MikTeX, run the MikTeX Console, switch the operation mode to Administrator, go to Settings > Directories, and either open or add your locally-managed TEXMF directory.  (On TeX Live, you would type `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` to find your local TeX tree, which is probably `c:\texlive\texmf-local` on Windows.)
- If it’s like the above, but for some reason you’re not compiling them on your own box, add a local directory in user mode, inside your user directory. (For TeX Live, you would use the directory in `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`, typically `%USERPROFILE%\texmf`.)

You can optionally run `fc-cache -f -s -v` and `luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v` to refresh your font caches for XeTeX and LuaTeX, but this should happen automatically whenever you request a font that isn’t in the cache.

If the files you need are named the same way as in the link you gave, I’d recommend you save the following commands to a file in your local TeX tree or your project folder, named `Futura.fontspec`. (**Warning:** This is untested.)

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Futura]{
   UprightFont = {* Book font},
   ItalicFont = {* Book Italic font},
   BoldFont = {* Bold font},
   BoldItalicFont = {* Bold Italic font},
   Extension = .ttf
}
```

Add whatever other font features you want and it supports, such as (perhaps) `Ligatures = Common` or `Numbers = OldStyle`.

Your document can now say

```
\setmainfont{Futura}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I uninstalled all Futura fonts on my user account and Installed for all users. My Error is now just coming from my naming convention for Futura italic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, `fontspec` does not seem to like spaces in filenames. For starters, try to use the font file (.ttf) directly: put the font files in your current working directory and rename them to remove the spaces. I used `FuturaBook.ttf` and `FuturaBookItalic.ttf`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FuturaBook.ttf}[ItalicFont={FuturaBookItalic.ttf}]

\begin{document}
  \Large Please help me write \emph{this text} in Futura!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compiled this with LuaLaTeX, by the way. Not entirely sure about XeLaTeX.

Comment: When I run this on my computer, I get this: 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")))
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "File not found: FuturaBook.ttf.".

! Package fontspec Error: The font "FuturaBook" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 ...aBook.ttf}[ItalicFont={FuturaBookItalic.ttf}]
                                                  
? 

Fonts are stored in the same folder as this file.

Comment: I updated my MiKTeX, but your MWE is not running. Same error message.

Comment: @Pyro1368, if you updated your miktex, please update the log in your question, it clearly shows a miktex needing updates.